# Immutable data structure for a DAG?

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming, immutability, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking for an immutable alternative to a data structure I saw used in a mutable program. (Seen in [this article](http://fmv.jku.at/papers/Biere-JSAT08.pdf), figure 4). It is a DAG where each node has two pointers. The rationale is we have multiple sets, and each element is part of two of the sets, with a link to its successor in each set. Thus the structure allows us to traverse along the elements of each set like we had a linked list for each one of them.

[image: Exotic two-watched literals data structure]

Linked lists are kind of popular in the functional and immutable world, but a doubly linked list offers great implementation challenges. It is said you can implement them with laziness, at least in some languages, but if a Scala programmer has a sequence where elements will be often removed or inserted in the middle, then you're probably just better off with a `Vector`.

To remove an element from this data structure using mutability, you just need to locate the two predecessors of an element, and replace their successors for the respective successor-successors.

Doing that in an immutable singly linked list forces us to rebuild all the predecessors, a price we might decide to pay, or to use `Stream` to remove the element lazily. But for this data structure here, we would now have to rebuild the two predecessors from the node, for both sets it belongs to, plus all its predecessors predecessors in all their sets!

I found this a quite interesting example of a data structure that poses great challenges for immutable design, and I am curious to find out now: what would be a good functional, immutable persistent way to implement this data structure? A similar challenge is probably faced in the design of a data structure for sparse matrices (as seen in [DLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links)).

The best I could come up with so far is to just go for an adjacency list stored in a `Map[Node,(Node,Node)]`. Would this be the best approach for this problem, sticking to immutability? Or could we turn this weird DAG-list into a tree, perhaps?... I often hear finger trees can solve anything, is there a remote chance we might use them in this case?

Comment: What are you using the DAG for? There are all sorts of solutions, but the answer depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The objective is to implement something called the "two watched literals" scheme to store a  CNF Boolean formula. We  have a set of lists of integers, and we need to be able to quickly retrieve the lists given either one of their first two elements, and also be able to update the whole structure (one of the watched literal gets removed, a new different number will be picked, but the other remains the same...)

Comment: So my actual problem is really how to manage these lists that are organized as elements that belong to two sets each, determined by their first two numbers. The answer might turn out to be something completely different, but the DAG on the figure is still an important reference, it's something people actually do in practice and that seems to work well. Except it's done in (very much) imperative and procedural implementations...

Comment: Sorry I  should have read the linked paper! it sounds like a very interesting problem. Hopefully someone will give you good answer—it looks like it will require some research and experimentation to find a decent immutable solution.

Comment: Right now I have implemented the DAG just like a regular tree or linked list, that works beautifully. The big question is how to delete items. I am going now for a "lazy removal", keeping a `Set[Int]` of numbers I should skip when traversing the DAG. It would be great to find out references of similar data structures that employ this technique.